# Why does entailment not hold in this case?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

[image]

I am having issue understanding something.

For the first formula:

$$(\exists z (R(z) \implies Q(z)))$$ This makes sense that this is true, because in interpretation $I$, there exists a $z$ ($z = 2$) such that $R(z)$ is false, thus $\exists z (R(z) \implies Q(z))$ must hold true vacously.

But how is

$$(\exists z R(Z)) \implies (\exists z Q(z))$$ A false statement?

If we take $z = 2$ then $\exists z R(z)$ is **false** thus this implication must be **true**

Can someone explain? Thanks very much!

Comment: You can't "take z = 2" in $\exists z ~ R z$ , you take whatever is true if anything is true, in this case z = 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you take instead $z=1,$ then $\exists z R(z)$ is true while $\exists z Q(z)$ is false, provided you mean in your interpretations that $R(1)$ is true but $Q(z)$ is always false for any $z.$

Answer (score 0):

If you take $z=2$, then $Rz$ is **false**. Not $\exists z:Rz$, just $Rz$.

However if you take $z=1$, then $Rz$ is **true**.

---

But we are not talking about the statement $Rz$. We are talking about

$$\exists z: Rz$$

which is **true if $Rz$ is true for at least one $z$**. And since $Rz$ is true for $z=1$, the statment $\exists z:Rz$ is true.